# Modify Linq to return first matching value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to modify the below Linq query to return the first matching row for the max version.

```
+----+------+---------+-----+
| PK | Name | Version | abc |
+----+------+---------+-----+
|  1 | Bill |       1 |   7 |
|  2 | Bob  |       1 |   2 |
|  3 | Ben  |       1 |   3 |
|  4 | Bob  |       2 |   2 |
|  5 | Ben  |       2 |   3 |
|  6 | Ben  |       2 |   3 |
+----+------+---------+-----+
```

Currently it would return:

```
 +----+------+---------+-----+
    | PK | Name | Version | abc |
    +----+------+---------+-----+
    |  1 | Bill |       1 |   7 |
    |  4 | Bob  |       2 |   2 |
    |  5 | Ben  |       2 |   3 |
    |  6 | Ben  |       2 |   3 |
    +----+------+---------+-----+
```

When I want it to return:

```
+----+------+---------+-----+
| PK | Name | Version | abc |
+----+------+---------+-----+
|  1 | Bill |       1 |   7 |
|  4 | Bob  |       2 |   2 |
|  5 | Ben  |       2 |   3 |
+----+------+---------+-----+

 var source = (from item in baseSource
                          where item.Version > 0 
                          where item.Published                           
                          where db.abcTest.Where(it => it.Published && it.Name == item.Name).Max(it => it.Version) == item.Version                              
                          orderby item.Name, item.Version descending                             
                          select new
                          {                         
                              item.PK,
                              item.Name,                                 
                              item.Version,
                              item.abc
                          }
                          ).ToList();
            return source;
```

Comment: may be `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Did you read about "group by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code using group function got it working

```
var source = (from item in baseSource

                          where item.Version > 0 
                          where item.Published                           
                          where db.abcTest.Where(it => it.Published && it.Name == item.Name).Max(it => it.Version) == item.Version

                          orderby item.Name, item.Version descending
                          group item by new { item.Name, item.Version} into groupx
                          select new
                          {          
                                PK = groupx.FirstOrDefault().PK,
                                groupx.Key.Name,
                                groupx.Key.Version,
                                abc= groupx.Select(it => it.abc.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
                          }
                          ).ToList();
            return source;
```

Comment: If you look closely I have also done the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need `GroupBy` here:-

```
var result = baseSource.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    var orderedObj = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Version)
                                      .ThenByDescending(z => z.abc).FirstOrDefault();
                    return new 
                            {
                                 PK = orderedObj.PK,
                                 Name = x.Key,
                                 Version = orderedObj.Version ,
                                 abc = orderedObj.abc
                             };
                };
```

Consider checking `orderedObj` for nulls otherwise it may throw Null reference exception.